# How to share code across models? (Rails 2.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a couple of methods I'd like to share between models rather than copying and pasting them. In a controller, I can do this by putting the methods in application_controller.rb which automatically gets included in every controller.
Is there a similar thing for models?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a file called `functionality.rb` or something similar in the `lib` directory of your Rails app. Make the file named after the module to autoload it when Rails starts. For example, if I wanted to add flagging to multiple models, I'd create a file called `lib/flagging.rb`, and it would look like this:

```
module Flagging
  # Flags an object for further review
  def flag!
    self.update_attribute(:flagged, true)
  end

  # Clears all flags on an object
  def deflag!
    self.update_attribute(:flagged, false)
  end
end
```

In every model I wanted to add this functionality to, I'd do the following:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Flagging
end
```

I'd then be able to do something like:

```
foo = Foo.create
foo.flag!
```

Comment: dude. It's all about the lib dir. I've started to put more code there and it is just convenient place to organize things.

Answer (score 4):

The top solution above worked for me. In Rails 3 I found I also had to update the application.rb file with: `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]` as answered here: [Best way to load module/class from lib folder in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356742/best-way-to-load-module-class-from-lib-folder-in-rails-3)

Answer (score 3):

You can either a) do something to similar to application_controller and create a model class from which others can subclass or b) use a module.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways you can share methods between 2 model classes.

- Use [inheritance](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_inheritance.html) if the models are related to each other, e.g. a shared parent class that contains the methods, or one subclasses the other that contains the methods.
- Use [modules/mixins](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/15/mixins-in-ruby/) that can be shared among multiple models

Comment: `Turn those methods into helper methods that both models have access to` - I thought models didn't have access to helper methods. How is that possible (seems like the cleanest method for what I'm trying to do)

Comment: You're right. I was thinking utility methods, not "helper methods" in the rails sense. So the mixin approach would be more useful than utility methods.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer by Josh, sometimes you might want to share some code defining a polymorphic association. You can't just put the `has_many` method call in your module, because  you will get an error, for example in a module called Votable:

```
undefined method `has_many' for Voteable:Module (NoMethodError)
```

So instead, you need to use the `self.included(base)` method and `base.instance_eval`. Here's an example with my `Voteable` module:

```
module Voteable

  def self.included(base)
    base.instance_eval do
      has_many :votes, as: :voteable
      has_many :voters, through: :votes
    end
  end

  def voted_up_by?(user)
    user and votes.exists?(value: 1, voter_id: user)
  end

  def voted_down_by?(user)
    user and votes.exists?(value: -1, voter_id: user)
  end

end
```

Now you can `include Voteable` in models that will have that behavior. This will execute the `self.included(base)` method and it will define the association on the including class.

Comment: In Rails 3 this is even easier—you can replace `def self.included(base) base.instance_eval` with `extend ActiveSupport::Concern included`.