# How can I make some code available throughout a Rails app conveniently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add a library that I wrote to a Rails app (and to other Rails apps later). I tried putting it in `/lib` which seemed logical...

```
[RAILS_ROOT]/lib/my_lib/the_main_file.rb
[RAILS_ROOT]/lib/my_lib/some_other_file.rb
```

Then...

```
require 'my_lib/the_main_file'
```

That works fine.

But is that a great way to do it?

Now I have to put that `require` everywhere I want to call the library.

I thought about putting the `require` in an initializer but that seems kind of weird.

What do people usually do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an initializer may look weird when you have a single file to include, but sometimes I have many files that I want to add, and end up using an intializer that only includes stuff. It's actually pretty neat.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the "best practices"(tm) or anything, but we do a similar thing for our project as well. The library is in `lib`, and the `require` in an initializer (`app_config.rb` in our case). This seems like a good way to do things, and hasn't bitten us in the butt thus far :) Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I usually wrap up my stuff in classes. If you add `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` to your `application.rb` then any reference to a missing constant will result in an attempt to autoload it, i.e just using `MyClass.new` will make it try to load `lib/my_class.rb'.

Have a look at [Best way to load module/class from lib folder in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356742/best-way-to-load-module-class-from-lib-folder-in-rails-3)