# What is the best way to load files from the lib folder that add methods to ~existing~ classes in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using `config.autoload_paths` in a way very similar to this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356742/best-way-to-load-module-class-from-lib-folder-in-rails-3) to load classes from the lib directory in a Rails 3 project.

Specifically, I've added these lines to the config/application.rb file:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

However, this method is not working for me for *existing* classes.  When I add a file like lib/extensions/string.rb:

```
class String
  def foo
    puts "foo"
  end
end
```

I get an `undefined method 'foo' for "":String`error.  Through various searches I've got the sense that this problem has to do with the lazy loading of these files.  I tried using `config.eager_load_paths` but was not able to get that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing *exactly* what you are describing in my application, and the only difference is that I *also* have an initializer called **extensions.rb** with the following code:

```
Dir.glob('lib/extensions/*').each { |f| require f }
```

Comment: This initializer method works for me.  However, I had to change it slightly to this: `Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/lib/extensions/*").each { |f| require f }`  Do you agree?

Comment: Also, there is a nice example of autoload vs. require referenced in another question in this [blog post](http://ablogaboutcode.com/2011/01/17/ruby-autoloading-explained/)

Comment: Using the full path is probably better, but wasn't needed for my application. Not sure why that would be though.

Comment: You ought to use eager_load_paths for thread safety and automatic reloaded classes on changes, as posted here http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/08/eager-loading-for-greater-good/