# where to add metaclass changes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I do something simple like

```
class Object
  def itworks
    "hoorah"
  end
end
```

and add this to lib/ I can't see any effect in the rails console. i.e "".itworks gives a method missing. Where is the proper place to add things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put this file in config\initializers, rails will load it in any environment.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to require it from somewhere that is loaded in your Rails app. A good place for this could be in config/application.rb if you want it to be used in all your configurations:

```
require "lib/my_helpers"
```

Answer (score 2):

the very same question was asked today; you need to load everything in lib.

[What is the best way to load files from the lib folder that add methods to ~existing~ classes in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842066/what-is-the-best-way-to-load-files-from-the-lib-folder-that-add-methods-to-exist)

Be sure to understand the difference between `require` and `autoload`