# Helper Classes for DelayedJob in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

In order to start delayed_job's on a schedule you need to have helper classes with a *perform* method that delayed_job can call. These need to be defined before any of the classes that use them to create scheduled delayed_jobs are called. All very short, and many of them in my case. For example:

```
class AccountUpdateJob < Struct.new(:account_id)
  def perform
    acct = Account.find(account_id)
    acct.api_update
  end
end
```

I'm doing this in a file called "dj_helper_classes" in the *initializers* folder. Is that the right thing to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I keep mine in lib/jobs, one file per class.  So, your example would be in lib/jobs/account_update_job.rb

```
module Jobs
    class AccountUpdateJob < Struct.new(:account_id)
        def perform
          acct = Account.find(account_id)
          acct.api_update
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: How do you make sure they all get loaded in time for use?

Comment: By default Rails3 does not autoload everything in the lib directory. You can make it do so by adding the following to application.rb           `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)`
`config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]`

Comment: It's probably worth noting that `application.rb` already contains the relevant lib autoload line, it's just commented out by default.

Comment: Here's some more discussion on autoloading the lib directory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356742/best-way-to-load-module-class-from-lib-folder-in-rails-3