# Rails 3 custom class NoMethodError error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, class, methods

I have added a custom class to the lib folder and can initialize the class and call an attribute but can not call a method from the class without getting the following error

undefined method `colour' for #

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using rails 3

Answer (score 0):

Can we see some code? Which version of rails?

My understanding is that not everything from lib is automatically loaded in rails 3.

See this post:
[Best way to load module/class from lib folder in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356742/best-way-to-load-module-class-from-lib-folder-in-rails-3)

Why not move the class to the models folder? I don't use lib so much anymore...

Comment: Moving it to the models folder should only be done if it's actually a model though...

Comment: Agreed... and I certainly didn't mean to suggest that one can or should throw anything in the models folder. But we could have a little debate about what a 'model' is, exactly.  All I really meant is that not every model should have to wrap a database table. It's fine to have plain ruby classes, or classes that include some, but not all ActiveModel modules, etc.