# How can I use classes in my RAILS_HOME/lib folder in my RAILS_HOME/config/environments/* files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, environment

I have configuration data (the host/post for a Redis server) that is managed by a class (RedisConfig) in my RAILS_HOME/lib folder. We decided to use redis-store as our cache.

This is what we have in RAILS_HOME/config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.cache_store = RedisStore.new "#{RedisConfig.host}:#{RedisConfig.port}"
```

I, of course, get a TypeError as RedisConfig is loaded AFTER production.rb is loaded, so it never exists in this context. Whats the best strategy for loading and using this configuration manager in our environment.rb or environments/#{RAILS_ENV}.rb files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider taking [this approach](http://blog.gipoo.net/2010/3/26/setting-up-the-redis).  The trick here is they get loaded during the initialisation stage - it's the same as including it in as an initialiser itself.

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356742/best-way-to-load-module-class-from-lib-folder-in-rails-3) on loading up your RedisConfig module.  While this is about engines, it's got some [interesting details on initialisation](http://www.cowboycoded.com/tag/initializers/).

**Update**

Here's a better solution - update your application.rb as follows

```
# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
# config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

This will autoload all modules stored in /lib.