# mongoid random from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

is It possible get a `shuffle/random` of a collection from action in controller.

```
def action
 #pseudocode something like the next:
 @objects = Object.random
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html
 end
end
```

I now can get shuffle from my view, with:

```
<% @objects.shuffle.each do |microfunc| %>
.
.
.
<% end %>
```

On view is possible with `each or for loop`. I don't want use loop to get random Object from one collection.

**How can I get random objects inside Mongoid::Criteria from my action controller?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a great way. Your choices:

- Store an integer for each document and get by its value: http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/random-attribute/
- use 'skip' which is inefficient: [Mongoid random document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759250/mongoid-random-document)

Comment: Thank you, but can you paste a example with mongoid? Thank you very much!

Comment: Those are both either mongoid or mongo