# Where do I put this matrix class in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, matrix

I am looking to use the matrix class shown here:

```
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Ruby
```

in my rails app. I have copied the class into lib/matrix.rb

In my view page I have tried to test this class by using the code:

```
<%= Matrix[[25,15,-5],[15,18,0],[-5,0,11]].cholesky_factor %>
```

However I get the error message:

```
undefined method `cholesky_factor' for Matrix[[25, 15, -5], [15, 18, 0], [-5, 0, 11]]:Matrix
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? (I have the require 'matrix' line in lib/matrix.rb too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `require 'matrix'` from `lib/matrix.rb`.

**Rename** to `lib/extend_matrix.rb` so we can specifically load it in.

In `config/application.rb`:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'rails/all'

require 'matrix' # <-- moved here

#...bundler stuff...

module MyApp # <-- don't overwrite this!
  class Application < Rails::Application
     # ...
    config.autoload_paths << "#{::Rails.root.to_s}/lib" # <-- set path
    require "extend_matrix" # <-- forcibly load your matrix extension
  # ...
```

Notice `#{::Rails.root.to_s}`. Use of `.to_s` is critical because `::Rails.root` returns a `Pathname` object. Without it, you will be adding `/lib` (system level) to the autoload path. We want `/path/to/rails/lib` (application level).

Remember to restart the server.

---

This is how I got it to work for me. If anybody knows how to do this without static requires, do share. I'm sure this can be done dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, it works when I try with a simple function but not with the Matrix class. I think there must be something wrong with the way I am extending the inbuilt Matrix class

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the lib/matrix.rb in never read. If you're using Rails 3, the files in the dir directory are not autoloaded. As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356742/best-way-to-load-module-class-from-lib-folder-in-rails-3), add the following line in your application.rb and restart your server:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"] # include all subdirectories
```

Comment: Thanks I have restarted the server and I am still getting the same error