# Ruby on Rails - Delayed job in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I need to do a delayed job to count fbLikes in Model but I have the error report of "undefined send_later() method". Is there any way to do delayed job to my fb_likes function in model?

==============================Latest===================================================

This is my latest code in my project. Things still the same, fb_likes does not display likes count.

[Company.rb]-MODEL

```
require "delayed_job"
require "count_job.rb"

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

before_save :fb_likes

    def fb_likes            
        Delayed::Job.enqueue(CountJob.new(self.fbId))
    end     
 end
```

[config/lib/count_job.rb]

```
class CountJob<Struct.new(:fbId)
def perform 
    uri = URI("http://graph.facebook.com/#{fbId}")
    data = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    self.fbLikes = JSON.parse(data)['likes']
end
end
```

[controller]

```
 def create 
    @company = Company.new(params[:company])

    if @company.save!
        flash[:success] = "New company successfully registered."
   ----and other more code----
```

Comment: You're now describing a different error than you were before. Please add a stack trace for the undefined send_later (nothing should be calling this method)

Comment: Your job's perform is also assigning to `self.fbLikes`, which doesn't exist. You can't save any data on the job class and should be storing the like data somewhere useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Library files are not required by default.

1. Rename the job file to `count_job.rb`. Using camelCase for filenames is insane and will burn you in unpredictable ways.
2. Create an initializer and add `require 'count_job.rb'`

Comment: I rename already but the problem still the same. I had added a latest code in my post.

Comment: I spent hours breaking my head over this. I found that delayed job was silently deleting the job from the DB when it wasn't finding the worker class. Adding a require statement in the initializer fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a separate worker that will get queued, the run to fetch the updated Model and call its fb_likes method on it, but the method will need to be public. Or take the logic into the worker itself.

Comment: can you show me a more solid example? I think I will misunderstood something... thanks..

Comment: Your code seems fine to me... Is the lib directory in your autoload path?

    config.autoload_paths << File.join(config.root, "lib")

Comment: I had put the require 'countJob' and it will not output error but my fb_likes does not output the facebook likes(seems the function cannot functions)

Comment: Sorry for late reply. You need to tell Rails to include the classes in your lib directory fot autoloading, otherwise Rails will not load these classes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356742/best-way-to-load-module-class-from-lib-folder-in-rails-3

Comment: copy config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]  into config/application.rb? It still cant work... I also copy config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)  Do I need to bundle install again?

Comment: I don't get why it's trying to load Company::CountJob 
Sorry if this sounds stupid, but are you sure you didn't declare CountJob somewhere else as well? Can you post full classes?

Comment: I added my latest code... Do my code have mistake somewhere? Thanks for helping me. =)

Comment: can you try something like Delayed::Job.enqueue(CountJob.new(self.fbId)) from the console? just to isolate the problem.

Comment: it report "syntax error near unexpected token `CountJob.new' "