# Show only exceptions messages to user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've created this code to show specific errors messages to user:

#### application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from Exception do |exception|
    message = exception.message
    message = "default error message" if exception.message.nil?

    render :text => message
  end
end
```

#### room_controller.rb

```
class RoomController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @room = Room.find(params[:room_id]) # Can throw 'ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound'
  end

  def business_method
    # something
    raise ValidationErros::BusinessException("You cant do this") if something #message "You cant do this" should be shown for user
    #...
  end

  def business_method_2
    Room.find(params[:room_id]).do_something
  end
end
```

#### room.rb

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  def do_something
    #...
    raise ValidationErrors::BusinessException("Invalid state for room") if something #message "Invalid state for room" should be shown for user
    #...
  end
end
```

#### app/models/erros/validation_errors.rb

```
module ValidationErrors
  class BusinessException < RuntimeError
    attr :message
    def initialize(message = nil)
      @message = message
    end
  end
end
```

#### example.js

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/room/show/' + roomId,
        success: function(data){
            //... do something with data
        },
        error: function(data){
            App.notifyError(data) //show dialog with message
        }
    });
```

But I can not use the class BusinessException. When BusinessException should be raised, 
the message

> uninitialized constant Room::ValidationErrors

is shown to user.

if I change this code:

```
raise ValidationErrors::BusinessException("Invalid state for room") if something
```

by this:

```
raise "Invalid state for room" if something
```

It works.

What change to this code works with BusinessException with messages. I need this
to create specifics `rescue_from` methods in ApplicationController.

**Edit:**

Thank you for comments!
My error is it doesn't know ValidationErrors Module. How to import this Module to my class?

I've tested add theses lines to  lines:

`require 'app/models/errors/validation_errors.rb'`

`require 'app/models/errors/validation_errors'`

But then raise the error:

`cannot load such file -- app/models/errors/validation_errors`

**Solution:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3356843/740394

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/errors)
```

Comment: It looks like it doesn't know ValidationErrors and it looks for it inside Room. Where did you put that file?

Comment: I would say you just need to have a `require 'app/models/erros/validation_errors.rb'` somewhere. It doesn't look like that file is getting loaded.

Comment: Ahhhhh! [**Do not rescue from Exception**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10048173/211563) unless you're re-raising it or know exactly what you're doing!

Comment: look my edit. The mistake is to import the module ValiationErrors!

Answer (score 0):

```
raise ::ValidationErrors::BusinessException("Invalid state for room")
```

Comment: This doesn't works. raise error `uninitialized constant ValidationErrors`

Comment: 'models' are already in the autoload path. for autoloader to pick up your file, your folder structure should match the class. You shouldn't manually 'require' within a Rails app.