# "Uninitialized constant" error when including a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to reference an association extension but it errors with:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant User::ListerExtension):
  app/models/user.rb:2:in `<class:User>'
```

Here is my implementation:

#### app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ListerExtension

  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles, :uniq => true, :extend => Lister
```

#### lib/lister.rb

```
module ListerExtension
  def lister
    self.map(&:to_s).join(', ')
  end
end
```

I am using Rails v3.1.3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to load module/class from lib folder in Rails 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356742/best-way-to-load-module-class-from-lib-folder-in-rails-3)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Andrew Marshall has an excellent point about the auto-load setup (see the question he links for more on that), but also:  Because you named your class `ListerExtension`, Rails will be looking for a file named `lister_extension.rb` - *not* `lister.rb`.  It's smart, but it's not that smart.

Comment: And [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/rubyonrails-talk/Ziq_0d-bJhI)'s a link with a few more useful details.

Comment: or create a initializer file ( in config/initializer) that requires your file, something like: 
require 'listener.rb'

Comment: This totally bit me today.  I updated the file name and all was right with my code again. :)

Comment: For anyone else, I noticed something like include ProfileHelper worked when rails server was running but not once restarted. I needed Api::ProfileHelper to make the server happy when starting.

Answer (score 0):

complementing the answer above

My problem was solved when I used require 'module-relative-path' in the file I want to include the module

```
require './lib/lister.rb' #check if this is the right relative path

 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ListerExtension

  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles, :uniq => true, :extend => Lister
```