# config.autoload_paths not working, unable to include modules in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, autoload

I have created a simple module and placed it in the lib directory and have included in the controller file.

below is the controller code.

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  include Departments
  def create
    user_data = Hash.new
    user_data["data"] = "hello world!"
    user_data["price"] = 12
    render :json => user_data
  end
end
```

when i try to execute it i see the below error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant UserController:: Departments):
```

I have searched forums and see that adding

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

solves the issue, but it did not in my case. I am using Rails 4.2.7.1 and ruby ruby 1.9.3p547.

Can anyone point out what could be the issue, Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the complete error?

Comment: added the full error message

Comment: Can you try replacing it with `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')`?

Comment: still the same, using both the above syntax i see the lib directory included when i execute "bin/rails r 'puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the naming convestion wrong, i created a sub directory under the lib folder by the name of my module and then created the file with the class name.rb and it worked.

Reference: ["Uninitialized constant" error when including a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525350/uninitialized-constant-error-when-including-a-module?rq=1)