# How to refer to an instance of a class in Rails in a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

I'm trying to dry up some code in my Rails application that allows to set a unique id when the object is creating using a filter. I have it in multiple locations and it seems like it should be in a module instead.

Right now I have something like this in each model.

```
  def set_uid
    self.uid = SecureRandom.uuid
  end
```

I have included a new file in my /lib directory at the file uid_generator.rb and included that the module in each of the models.

```
//model   
include UidGenerator

module UidGenerator
  def set_uid
    self.uid = SecureRandom.uuid
  end
end
```

In my testing however, this yields the error

```
uninitialized constant MODELNAME::UidGenerator (NameError).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to configure the autoload paths for your rails application. Here is something might be helpful. [Best way to load module/class from lib folder in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356742/best-way-to-load-module-class-from-lib-folder-in-rails-3)

Comment: Right now I've got this path: config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/modules/)

Comment: If you want to put it in lib/modules then you need to call you module "Modules::UidGenerator" for autoloading to work.

Comment: Thanks, I found this blog post helpful as well: http://www.williambharding.com/blog/technology/rails-3-autoload-modules-and-classes-in-production/