# Rails - Accessing module method in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, module

So, I've read it all:

- [Best way to load module/class from lib folder in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356742/best-way-to-load-module-class-from-lib-folder-in-rails-3)
- [Rails doesn't load my module from lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202690/rails-doesnt-load-my-module-from-lib)
- [Rails /lib modules and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073076/rails-lib-modules-and)
- [How to create and use a module using Ruby on Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906932/how-to-create-and-use-a-module-using-ruby-on-rails-3)

But I can't make it work. Here's my situation:

I have a `calc_distance(place1, place2)` method and an attribute `places` to my `User` model and I want to define a method `calc_total_distance` in the `User` model.

I want to access the `calc_distance` method through a `Utils` lib and not to load the whole utils when using it.

In `/lib/utils.rb`

```
module Utils
  def calc_distance a, b
    # Blah blah blah
  end
end
```

In `/config/application.rb` I have:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

In the console, I can do
`include Utils` then `calc_distance(place1, place2)` and it works. But `Utils::calc_distance(place1 place2)` doesn't work ...

Extra-question is can I do this ?

Then in my `User.rb` model:

```
  def get_total_distance
    # Blah blah blah
    dist += calc_distance(place1, place2)
    # Blah blah blah
  end
```

returns me `undefined method 'include' for #<User:0x00000006368278>`

and

```
  def get_total_distance
    # Blah blah blah
    dist += Utils::calc_distance(place1, place2)
    # Blah blah blah
  end
```

returns me `undefined method 'calc_distance' for Utils:Module`

How can I achieve this, knowing that I really prefer the second method (which as I reckon, doesn't load the whole Utils module ...

Comment: can you try `include Utils` to user.rb?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't wan't to do mixin, but just to define some Utils' methods, then you can define the methods on module level (using self. prefix):

```
module Utils
  def self.calc_distance a, b
    # Blah blah blah
  end
end
```

and then call them this way:

```
Utils.calc_distance(place1, place2)
```

instead of

```
Utils::calc_distance(place1, place2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Athlete < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Utils
  def get_total_distance
    # Blah blah blah
    dist += calc_distance(place1, place2)
    # Blah blah blah
  end
end
```

Comment: So I'd go for the first solution. No solution for doing Utils::calc_distance? Ain't I loading too many methods instead of only the one I need?

Comment: No, u can't load only one method of module. If you want like that you have to create different module with particular method

Comment: Ok, so when is it I should use `Module::method` as a syntax?