# Facing runtime error NameError (uninitialized constant) for modules, classes placed in lib folder after upgrading Rails to 5.0.0.1 from 4.2.5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, nameerror

I have two separate Rails applications

- one just exposes an API (henceforth termed as **API-app**) and
- another one acts as an Administration Portal (henceforth termed as **AdminPortal**) for managing the data in API-app.

Both are presently running on Rails **4.2.5.1** on **staging** as well as **production** environments. However on a **staging_experimental** environment I upgraded both the applications to Rails **5.0.0.1**. I have rspecs for the both the applications and the spec suite in both the applications is passing and Capistrano deployment goes success. However when trying to send request to API-endpoint in API-app I face a runtime error

> NameError (uninitialized constant Api::BaseController::ApiTokenAuthentication)

**/lib/api_token_authentication.rb**

```
module ApiTokenAuthentication
  <some module_functions defined here>
end
```

and the module functions are accessed in my controller in following manner:

```
class Api::BaseController < ActionController::Base
  def authenticate!(user)
     ApiTokenAuthentication.my_module_function_here(user)
  end
end
```

The same kind of runtime-error **NameError (uninitialized constant ...)** errors are also encountered in AdminPortal too and they refer to the code placed in AdminPortal's codebase's **lib** folder. For e.g.

> NameError (uninitialized constant MyApiApp::Api):
>
> NameError (uninitialized constant MyApiApp::Api::Get):
>
> NameError (uninitialized > constant MyApiApp::Api::Post):

**/lib/my_api_app**

**/lib/my_api_app/api.rb**

```
module MyApiApp
  module Api
  end
end
```

**/lib/my_api_app/api/get.rb**

```
module MyApiApp
  module Api
    class Get < BaseRequest
    end
  end
end
```

**/lib/my_api_app/api/post.rb**

```
module MyApiApp
  module Api
    class Post < BaseRequest
    end
  end
end
```

**/lib/my_api_app/api/base_request.rb**

```
module MyApiApp
  module Api
    class BaseRequest
    end
  end
end
```

**/lib/my_api_app/api/base_response.rb**

```
module MyApiApp
  module Api
    class BaseResponse
    end
  end
end
```

Searching for a solution to fix these errors I found following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13202812/936494) which mentioned to explicitly require the path in an initializer file. For e.g.

**/config/initializers/load_my_api_app_api_utility_classes.rb**

```
require File.join(Rails.root, "lib/my_api_app/api.rb")

lib_api_dir_path = Rails.root.join("lib", "my_api_app", "api").to_s

Dir["#{lib_api_dir_path}/*.rb"].each {|file| require file }
```

After adding the above initializer the errors in AdminPortal app went away

> NameError (uninitialized constant MyApiApp::Api):
>
> NameError (uninitialized constant MyApiApp::Api::Get):
>
> NameError (uninitialized > constant MyApiApp::Api::Post):

but as soon as AdminPortal app sent request to the end-point exposed by API-app I started encountering following error (mentioned previously)

> NameError (uninitialized constant Api::BaseController::ApiTokenAuthentication)

So I think there is some basic thing which is missing and which is causing the errors related to auto-loading of code residing in the **lib** folder and which is used by the controller classes. I am really puzzled on why this is happening because I have checked `/config/application.rb` and in both the applications `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')` is already there.

The same code is working without any issues on **staging** and **production** envs wherein the application is running on Rails 4.2.5.1.

Also not facing these errors with the upgraded code on **development** environment on my local machine.

Can anybody please shed light on this and guide me towards the resolution of this weird error?

### Update - Oct 19, 2016

I received following answer [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26814#issuecomment-254538300) to my questions above

> Autoload is disabled in any environment that has eager_load enabled.
>   You should never add lib to autoload_paths. Use eager_autoload_paths.
>   All this information is being explained in the upgrading guide
>   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#autoloading-is-disabled-after-booting-in-the-production-environment

I tried using the `eager_load_paths` approach but it started throwing new errors. As there are lot of details I have to share after using `eager_load_paths`, I have added them to a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/jiggneshhgohel/ba15292a8991e23047cfaa7ddd62d257)

Hoping to receive some guidance soon.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found that there is no need neither to add anything to `autoload_paths` nor to `eager_load_paths` nor to explicitly add `config.enable_dependency_loading = true` to `/config/environments/.rb`

The reason being the utility code, which was supposed to be eager-loaded on production-kind environments i.e. production, staging etc is moved to a directory under `app` folder and as mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19852844/936494

> ```
> Another interesting quirk is that in every rails app, all directories under app/ are
> automatically in both autoload_paths and eager_load_paths, meaning that adding a directory there requires no further actions.
> ```

This way we automatically get rid of runtime errors faced like `NameError (uninitialized constant MyNamespace::Api)`.

Thanks.

Comment: No. Moving the utility code to `app` folder helped without needing to make any changes to `autoload_paths` or `eager_load_paths` or enabling  `enable_dependency_loading`