# uninitialized constant when using module in custom initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, initialization

I'm working on a Rails (3.2) app and I need to execute some tasks when the app boots.

Since I want to keep the logic in a separate file I have also create lib/helinium.rb that looks like (with dummy run method)

```
class Helinium
  def self.run
    puts "running ...."
  end
end
```

And I have created a simple  initializer file config/initializers/perform_checks.rb

```
Helinium.run
```

And everything seems fine.
Now I wish to put the Helinium class within a module so the two files look respectively like

```
module Elemens
  class Helinium
      def self.run
        puts "running ...."
      end
  end
end
```

and

```
Elemens::Helinium.run
```

but when I try to boot the app I get

**uninitialized constant Elemens (NameError)**

Am I missing something here? Why the module is not found?

Thanks and have a nice day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### explanation

This has something to do how the autoloading works in Rails.

Rails doesn't automatically require everything under /lib. It only auto loads when you try to use a new class name that matches a file name in lib.

You may check this post for more info:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9819938/1188913

### fix

To fix your issue you could

```
require 'lib/helinium'
```

OR

put the class into a folder called `lib\elemens`

Comment: Thanks I though adding the following line to application.rb would be enough but actually it wasn't.

 config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)

Comment: it really depends on how you name the class inside and where you place it. You can also put the class into an 'elemens' folder to make it work.

Comment: So if I have lib/elemens/helinium.rb I don't need to require the file. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Sorry If I bother you again but is there a way to ensure my initializer is executed as last operation during the boot? I need to know the available models. I call  ActiveRecord::Base.descendants but it returns an empty array. Thanks again.

Comment: no worries, maybe this is something for a new question? Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem