# Where to store globally shared data structures in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a data structure like this in one of my models:

```
def image_size_limits
    {
        "web" => {"maxheight" => 480, "maxwidth" => 680, "minheight" => 400, "minwidth" => 600}, 
        "phone" => {"height" => 345, "width" => 230, "minheight" => 300, "minwidth" => 200},
        "tablet" => {"height" => 680, "width" => 480, "minheight" => 600, "minwidth" => 400},
        "other" => {"height" => 680, "width" => 480, "minheight" => 600, "minwidth" => 400}
    }
end
```

I use this in a custom validator I have to validate the sizes of images uploaded. I would like to be able to use this data structure not just in this one model - but everywhere. In all my models, views and controllers.

How would I go about doing that, where would I put it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a **module**.

Stick it in your `lib` directory. (You may need to configure Rails 3 to autoload classes and modules from your `lib` folder. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356742/best-way-to-load-module-class-from-lib-folder-in-rails-3).)

```
# lib/image_sizes.rb

module ImageSizes
  def image_size_limits
    {
      "web" => {"maxheight" => 480, "maxwidth" => 680, "minheight" => 400, "minwidth" => 600}, 
      "phone" => {"height" => 345, "width" => 230, "minheight" => 300, "minwidth" => 200},
      "tablet" => {"height" => 680, "width" => 480, "minheight" => 600, "minwidth" => 400},
      "other" => {"height" => 680, "width" => 480, "minheight" => 600, "minwidth" => 400}
    }
  end
end
```

Then in your models or controllers:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ImageSizes
  # ...
end


class MyController < ApplicationController
  include ImageSizes
  # ...
end
```

Now, each model or controller that includes the `ImageSizes` module will have access to the module's methods, namely `image_size_limits`.

Comment: In Rails 4, there will also be concerns. Check this out: http://railscasts.com/episodes/400-what-s-new-in-rails-4

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to create an initializer file and declare a constant there.

```
# config/initializers/image_size_limits.rb

IMAGE_SIZE_LIMITS = {
  "web" => {"maxheight" => 480, "maxwidth" => 680, "minheight" => 400, "minwidth" => 600}, 
  "phone" => {"height" => 345, "width" => 230, "minheight" => 300, "minwidth" => 200},
  "tablet" => {"height" => 680, "width" => 480, "minheight" => 600, "minwidth" => 400},
  "other" => {"height" => 680, "width" => 480, "minheight" => 600, "minwidth" => 400}
}
```

Then in your model or controller, just use `IMAGE_SIZE_LIMITS['web']['maxheight']` to get `480`.