# convert a ruby rails model class into a class in the lib folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, shared-libraries

I have the following model/Admin.rb class that I would like to extract and convert into a lib/UserApi class.  I am not familiar into creating lib classes and being able to call them from my controllers.  Any advice appreciated.

```
class Admin
attr_accessor :id
attr_accessor :firstname
attr_accessor :lastname
attr_accessor :usergroups

def initialize json_attrs = {}
    @usergroups = []
    unless json_attrs.blank?
        @id = json_attrs["id"]
        @fname = json_attrs["fname"]
        @lname = json_attrs["lname"]
        @groups = json_attrs["groups"]
        @authenticated = true
    end
    if json_attrs.blank?
        @firstname = "blank"
    end
end

def is_authenticated?
    @authenticated ||= false
end

def in_groups? group_names
    return !(@usergroups & group_names).empty? if group_names.kind_of?(Array)
    @usergroups.include?(group_names)
end

def authenticate username, password
    options={:basic_auth => {:username => CONFIG[:API_CLIENT_NAME], 
                            :password => CONFIG[:API_CLIENT_PASSWORD]}}

    api_response = HTTParty.get("#{CONFIG[:API_HOST]}auth/oauth2?username=#{username}&password=#{password}", options)

    raise "API at #{CONFIG[:API_HOST]} is not responding" if api_response.code == 500 || api_response.code == 404

    if api_response.parsed_response.has_key? "error"
        return false
    else
        initialize(api_response.parsed_response["user"].select {|k,v| ["id", "fname", "lname", "groups"].include?(k) })
        @authenticated = true
        return true
    end
end

def full_name
    "#{@name} #{@name}"
end
```

end

This is what I currently use in the auth_controller"

```
class Admin::AuthController < Admin::BaseController

def auth
    admin_user = Admin.new
    auth_result = admin_user.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the UserApi class in the lib directory:

```
# lib/user_api.rb
class UserApi
 ...
```

Update the controller:

```
class Admin::AuthController < Admin::BaseController

def auth
    admin_user = UserApi.new
    auth_result = admin_user.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])
end
```

Load the classes you put in your lib/ directory, so they are accessible in the controller: [Best way to load module/class from lib folder in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356742/best-way-to-load-module-class-from-lib-folder-in-rails-3)

I typically create a `config/initializers/00_requires.rb` file and require the lib files I need.