# Ruby on Rails - undefined method name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i'm trying to send information from a form to the FRESHDESK API but having a very difficult time accomplishing this

in my routes

```
 resource :client, only: [:create, :show]
```

i set up a resource

then i created a controller

clients_controller.rb

```
 class ClientsController < ApplicationController 
 def show
 end

 def create
   client = Freshdesk.new("http://onehouse.freshdesk.com/", "xs02V99BeqPfDiAlwcL7", "X")
   client.post_tickets(params[:client])
 end
end
```

then in clients/show.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@client) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :subject %>
  <%= f.text_field :subject %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_field :description %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
 <% end %>
```

i also have a freshdesk.rb in my lib directory

```
       require "rest_client"
 require 'nokogiri'

 class Freshdesk

 # custom errors
 class AlreadyExistedError < StandardError; end
 class ConnectionError < StandardError; end

 attr_accessor :base_url

 def initialize(base_url, username, password)

 @base_url = base_url

 RestClient.add_before_execution_proc do | req, params |
  req.basic_auth username, password
 end
end

# Freshdesk API client support "GET" with id parameter optional
#   Returns nil if there is no response
def self.fd_define_get(name, *args)
  name = name.to_s
  method_name = "get_" + name

define_method method_name do |*args| 
  uri = mapping(name)
  uri.gsub!(/.xml/, "/#{args}.xml") if args.size > 0

    begin
      response = RestClient.get uri
    rescue Exception
      response = nil
    end
  end
end

# Freshdesk API client support "DELETE" with the required id parameter
def self.fd_define_delete(name, *args)
  name = name.to_s
  method_name = "delete_" + name

  define_method method_name do |args|
    uri = mapping(name)
    raise StandardError, "An ID is required to delete" if args.size.eql? 0
    uri.gsub!(/.xml/, "/#{args}.xml")
    RestClient.delete uri
  end
end

# Freshdesk API client support "POST" with the optional key, value parameter
#
#  Will throw: 
#    AlreadyExistedError if there is exact copy of data in the server
#    ConnectionError     if there is connection problem with the server
def self.fd_define_post(name, *args)
  name = name.to_s
  method_name = "post_" + name

  define_method method_name do |args|
    raise StandardError, "Arguments are required to modify data" if args.size.eql? 0
    uri = mapping(name)

    builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
      xml.send(doc_name(name)) {
        args.each do |key, value|
          xml.send(key, value)
        end
      }
    end

    begin 
      response = RestClient.post uri, builder.to_xml, :content_type => "text/xml"

    rescue RestClient::UnprocessableEntity
      raise AlreadyExistedError, "Entry already existed"

    rescue RestClient::InternalServerError
      raise ConnectionError, "Connection to the server failed. Please check hostname"

    rescue RestClient::Found
      raise ConnectionError, "Connection to the server failed. Please check username/password"

    rescue Exception => e3
      raise
    end   

    response   
  end
end

# Freshdesk API client support "PUT" with key, value parameter
#
#  Will throw: 
#    ConnectionError     if there is connection problem with the server
def self.fd_define_put(name, *args)
  name = name.to_s
  method_name = "put_" + name

  define_method method_name do |args|
    raise StandardError, "Arguments are required to modify data" if args.size.eql? 0
    raise StandardError, "id is required to modify data" if args[:id].nil?
    uri = mapping(name)

    builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
      xml.send(doc_name(name)) {
        args.each do |key, value|
          xml.send(key, value)
        end
      }
    end

    begin 
      uri.gsub!(/.xml/, "/#{args[:id]}.xml")
      response = RestClient.put uri, builder.to_xml, :content_type => "text/xml"

    rescue RestClient::InternalServerError
      raise ConnectionError, "Connection to the server failed. Please check hostname"

    rescue RestClient::Found
      raise ConnectionError, "Connection to the server failed. Please check username/password"

    rescue Exception => e3
      raise
    end   

    response   
  end
end

[:tickets, :ticket_fields, :users, :forums, :solutions, :companies].each do |a|
  fd_define_get a
  fd_define_post a  
  fd_define_delete a
  fd_define_put a
end


# Mapping of object name to url:
#   tickets => helpdesk/tickets.xml
#   ticket_fields => /ticket_fields.xml
#   users => /contacts.xml
#   forums => /categories.xml
#   solutions => /solution/categories.xml
#   companies => /customers.xml
def mapping(method_name)
  path = case method_name
    when "tickets" then File.join(@base_url + "helpdesk/tickets.xml")
    when "ticket_fields" then File.join( @base_url, "ticket_fields.xml")
    when "users" then File.join(@base_url, "contacts.xml")
    when "forums" then File.join(@base_url + "categories.xml")
    when "solutions" then File.join(@base_url + "solution/categories.xml")
    when "companies" then File.join(@base_url + "customers.xml")
  end
end

# match with the root name of xml document that freskdesk uses
def doc_name(name)
  doc = case name 
      when "tickets" then "helpdesk_ticket"
      when "ticket_fields" then "helpdesk-ticket-fields"
      when "users" then "user"
      when "companies" then "customer"
      else raise StandardError, "No root object for this call"
    end
  end
end
```

when i try to run this i get a

```
   NoMethodError in Clients#show
   undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

So im guessing theres something im missing in my show action but unsure what i am suppose to put

just on a side note....i first had everything in a single ruby file and in my terminal i executed

```
 $ ruby freshdesk.rb
```

and it ran fine and posted the data to my FRESHDESK DASHBOARD

so now im just trying to get it working in my RAILS APP

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize @client in your action to use it in your view

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController 
 def show
   @client = Freshdesk.new("http://onehouse.freshdesk.com/", "xs02V99BeqPfDiAlwcL7", "X")
 end

 def create
   client = Freshdesk.new("http://onehouse.freshdesk.com/", "xs02V99BeqPfDiAlwcL7", "X")
   client.post_tickets(params[:client])
 end
end
```

This should fix your problem

Comment: = thanks for the reply ive tried that and i get a uninitialized constant ClientsController::Freshdesk any idea how to fix that?

Comment: rails doesn't automatically load the classes from lib. Add this to your config/application.rb -> `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]`

Comment: have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356742/best-way-to-load-module-class-from-lib-folder-in-rails-3

Comment: that seemed to get over that hurdle but with @client = Freshdesk.new in my show action i get this error ArgumentError in ClientsController#show

Comment: @RickyAhn see my edit to Vimsha's answer. You need to pass the arguments to `new` in the `show` action too. If that fixes your problem you might want to extract that into a helper method so you don't repeat the code :)

Comment: @alfonso Thanks for the suggestion...after i added the argument i got a no method error again NoMethodError in Clients#show --- my show action has this inside of it -@client = Freshdesk.new("http://onehouse.freshdesk.com/", "xs02V99BeqPfDiAlwcL7", "X") and my form for has this <%= form_for(@client) do |f| %>

Comment: i just got rid of the @ symbol in my show controller and in my form i just used :client and specified the url client_path it works now!!!