# Rails: requiring a library in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following way works perfectly

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/mymodule/class1.rb"
```

But why do do I have to put `#{Rails.root}`

Comment: You should instead tell Rails to autoload `lib`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356742/best-way-to-load-module-class-from-lib-folder-in-rails-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Ruby 2.0, Ruby no longer considers the current directory to be in the require path. You could also use `require ./lib/mymodule/class1.rb`.

Comment: ha! okay thanks! so now which is the right way? Rails.root or .?

Comment: The "right" way is to configure Rails to autoload `lib`, as I mentioned in the comment below your question.