# Rails: requiring a non-gem library

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This has got to be a duplicate question, but I can't find the magic words on Google.

What are the best practices when including a library that *isn't* a gem (in other words: a library that is part of Ruby but nonetheless requires an explicit `require`)? Should I require it in `config/environment.rb`?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356742/best-way-to-load-module-class-from-lib-folder-in-rails-3

Comment: @prusswan: I don't think that's what I want; I'm trying to include a library that is part of Ruby but still requires an explicit `require`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your config directory there is a initializers directory. There you can create a rb file with your `include` statement