# How to display results from a JSON feed in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I have a script that I have written in ruby to parse all the `titles` in external JSON feed. Now I have to show them as `data-source` for the typeahead utility of twitter bootstrap.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

result = JSON.parse(open("http://data.example.com/locations.json").read)

result.each do |bldg|
    puts bldg['title']
end
```

So I want to use the above snippet in the rails app.

**How to apply some custom ruby inside a Rails app?**

Thanks!

Comment: retitled to be same as content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the lib folder and then call it where needed.

Here are some great resources:

- [Love your lib directory](http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/ruby/2012/02/14/love-your-lib-directory.html)
- [What code goes in the lib directory?](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/02/07/what-code-goes-in-the-lib-directory/)
- [How to load lib files (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356742/best-way-to-load-module-class-from-lib-folder-in-rails-3)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As an example

```
result = `#{Rails.root.join('script/custom.rb')}`
```