# Auto include in Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, include

I find myself having to type (for example)

> include PathHelper

every time I load the Rails Console.

Is there a way to configure the Rails console to automatically include certain modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still looking for an answer, this is what I do, 
I created a file `~/.irbrc` in which you put all the code you want to be auto loaded in your rails console.

This is the content of my file:

```
require "awesome_print"
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

AwesomePrint.irb!
def y(obj)
  puts obj.to_yaml
end
```

Comment: Yup, you nailed it. Thx!!

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for configuring rails console has changed. I found this on RailsGuides:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration

```
console do
  # this block is called only when running console,
  # so we can safely require pry here
  require "pry"
  config.console = Pry
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone still feel confused, the simplest way to do this is:

1. go to the root directory of your project
2. create an `.irbrc` file(if you use `rails console`) or `.pryrc` file(if you use `pry`)
3. put whatever you need to include in it

For example, if you use the default rails console and need to `include PathHelper`, just put it in the file:

```
# RootDirectoryOfYourProject/.irbrc 
include PathHelper
```

The `PathHelper` will be included automatically when you do `rails console`

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3356843/3259320).

Basically, modify your `config/application.rb` file to include the paths to any modules you want to auto-load.

Comment: I am not aware of Rails applications having a config.rb file. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it is not working. Error each time.