# How to require a file only for console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've a Ruby class that I will use only for console, it monkey patches `ActiveRecord::Base` with some shortcuts like `ua` for `update_attribute` and I don't want to load it when running `rails server` but only when running the `rails console` command.

What is the way to achieve this?

Comment: Please dont answer with `.irbrc` because I want this to work for a single project only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`rails console` defines `Rails::Console`

So you can do

```
if defined?(Rails::Console)
  # this runs only in rails console
end
```

Another approach would be to use `config/application.rb`:

```
module MyApplication
  class Application < Rails::Application
    console do
      require 'my_console_file'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: a file in initialize would be a good place to put this? remember that i want to monkey path ActiveRecord classes

Comment: This seems to work only for Rails 3+, any idea for rails 2.3?

Comment: An initializer sounds like a good idea. As for rails 2.3, sorry I have no idea. Isn't `Rails::Console` getting defined?

Comment: Hm, I wish this worked, but putting it in an initializer doesn't actually seem to require the files I want it to, at least when using the Rails 4+ spring-ified console (don't know how to test without Spring). EDIT: This answer worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31961065/337446

Comment: `rails c`
Running via Spring preloader in process 3170
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.1)
2.3.0 :001 > `defined?(Rails::Console)`
 => "constant"

Comment: @swrobel It's working for me in Rails 5.0.1 with Spring. I have updated my answer with your suggestion though, it's a good approach nonetheless. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a new environment, "console", by copying one of the existing ones and making the desired changes, and then always launch the console in that environment.  This seems like it will cut down on accidental side-effect syndrome.