# How to include a helper method in a deep class with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a method in `app/helpers/logs_helper.rb`:

```
def product_name(id)
  Product.find_by_id(id).name
end
```

I want to use this `product_name` in `app/helpers/logs_helper/products_log_helper.rb`:

```
module LogsHelper
  module ProductsLogHelper
    def search(params)
      product_log_name = product_name(params[:id])
    end
  end
end
```

But it can't find `product_name` even I use:

```
include LogsHelper
```

in the `products_log_helper.rb` file.

How to do this? I am using Rails 3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A helper method is visible to the views (and by extension the controller); they're not really a place to put "general purpose functions", but rather functions for your views.

What you probably want to do, is probably make an `app/classes/log.rb`:

```
class Log
  def self.product_name id
    Product.find_by_id(id).name
  end
end
```

After which you can use this everywhere in your Rails app:

```
Log.product_name 42
```

You *could* also get a controller instance, but this is hacky:

```
helpers = ApplicationController.new.view_context
helpers.product_name 42
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but this method could also be on your model::

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def self.get_name_by_id id
    self.find_by_id(id).name
  end
end
```

After which you can just use:

```
Product.get_name_by_id 42
```

Comment: I agree with this other than, it's been convention to use `lib/my_mclass` - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356742/best-way-to-load-module-class-from-lib-folder-in-rails-3)

Comment: @Anthony The downside of the `/lib` directory is that you need to reload the entire rails app when you change a file there (unless you configure Rails to do something different), which is not the case with `/app/classes` (or any other subdirectory in `/app/`).

Comment: Thank you very much. You give me three good methods! Learned some good practices!