# Rails doesn't seem to load stuff in `lib` directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wanted to refactor some code out of a controller into a module, so I put the file into `lib`.

```
# lib/updat_lock.rb
module UpdateLock
  # ...
end

# app/controllers/boilerplates_controller.rb
class BoilerplatesController < InheritedResources::Base
  include UpdateLock
  # ...
end
```

But sadly, the file doesn't seem to be loaded, as I get an `uninitialized constant BoilerplatesController::UpdateLock` exception. What's wrong here? I thought the `lib` folder is always loaded automatically?

**Update**

Although a solution was provided, the thing I have forgotten was adding a `require 'update_lock'` on top of my controller file.

Comment: You could try `::UpdateLock`, but the solution really depends on whether or not the file is really `updat_lock` (i.e., misspelled) and which version of Rails.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356742/best-way-to-load-module-class-from-lib-folder-in-rails-3 check this

Comment: it isn't loaded automatically, by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this line to application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Comment: While this works, it is actually a better idea to use `eager_load_paths` instead of `autoload_paths`. See [this blog post](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/11/dont-forget-about-eager-load-when-extending-autoload/). In the development environment however, you won't notice a difference :)

Comment: Oh, I thought this is done by default by Rails. But I guess I was just confused because `lib` is in the load path, I mixed this up a little. So I just have to put a `require 'update_lock'` on top of my controller, and everything is working fine. Thanks!